# Problems in tree

Tags: graph-theory

Please give me some hints for the following problems. Many thanks in advance, Prove that

1. For any three nodes $ u $ , $ v $ and $ w$ of a tree $ d(u,v)+d(v,w)+d(u,w)\equiv 0$ (mod 2).
2. For any four nodes $u$, $v$, $w$ and $x$ in a tree numbers $ d(u,v)+d(w,x)$, $ d(u,w)+d(v,x)$ and $d(u,x)+d(v,w)$ are not all distinct.

Comment: Do you see why, in a tree, there is a unique path from $u$ to $v$, no matter what $u$ and $v$ are?

Comment: I think I found the answer of question 1 but question 2?

Comment: If you think you have the answer to question 1, you should write it up, and post it here as an answer.

Comment: Meanwhile, think about the unique path fact I mentioned. Can you show that either there are vertices $a$ and $b$ (among $u$, $v$, $w$, and $x$) such that $c$ and $d$ are on the path from $a$ to $b$, or else there is a vertex $a$ that is on the way from $b$ to $c$ and from $b$ to $d$ and from $c$ to $d$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: For the first question make $u$ the root of the tree, let $P_v$ be the path from $u$ to $v$, and let $P_w$ be the path from $u$ to $w$; $d(u,v)$ is the length of $P_v$, and $d(u,w)$ is the length of $P_w$. There are three possibilities:

- $w$ lies on $P_v$;
- $v$ lies on $P_w$; or
- the intersection of $P_v$ and $P_w$ is a path from $u$ to some vertex $x$, and the paths from $x$ to $v$ and from $x$ to $w$ meet only at $x$.

In each case $d(u,v)+d(v,w)+d(u,w)$ is the sum of the lengths of several paths, each of which is counted twice, so it must be even. For example, in the first case $$d(u,v)=d(u,w)+d(w,v)\;,$$ so the sum is $2d(u,w)+2d(w,v)$.

**Added:** For the second question, without loss of generality assume that the path $P$ between $u$ and $v$ is of maximal length among the six paths between pairs of vertices in $\{u,v,w,x\}$. Show that the paths from $w$ to $u$ and $v$ meet $P$ at some vertex $y\notin\{u,v\}$, and the paths from $x$ to $u$ and $v$ meet $P$ at some vertex $z\notin\{u,v\}$. Without loss of generality assume that $y$ lies on the path from $u$ to $z$. (It’s possible that $y=z$.) Then show that

$$d(u,v)+d(w,x)=d(u,x)+d(w,v)\;;$$

the two sides comprise the same path segment, just divided up differently.

Comment: My answer is the same answer with a little change, but your answer is better. thanks very much.

Comment: @mehranian: You’re welcome. Let me guess: you also analyzed cases, but you didn’t notice that taking one of the three vertices to be the root reduces the number of cases significantly?

Comment: yes, you're right.